# How to concatenate date and time columns based on value from another column in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, concatenation

I have three Columns in my SQL Table: `Date`, `Time`, and `Check`.

I want to concatenate Date and Time value together into a datetime column based on Check Column.

The Check column contains a varchar value either 'Today' or 'Tomorrow'. So, if the Check value is 'Today', the Time should concatenate with today's date, else if Check value is 'tomorrow', the time should concatenate with tomorrow's date.

Is there a way to concatenate two columns based on another column with SQL statements?

Comment: So you don't need `Date` column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a select then you can do as

```
select
date,
time,
case 
 when check = 'Today' then concat(curdate(),' ',time)
 when check = 'Tomorrow' then concat( date_add(curdate(),interval 1 day) ,' ', time ) 
 else concat(date,' ', time) 
 end as datetime
from table_name
```

Now if you want to update then you can do as

```
update table_name 
set 
datetime =  case 
     when check = 'Today' then concat(curdate(),' ',time) 
     when check = 'Tomorrow' then concat( date_add(curdate(),interval 1 day) ,' ', time ) 
     else concat(date,' ', time)
```

You can ignore the `else` part or set it to something else as per your need.